# Функция увеличения числа на единицу

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Вот есть элементарный код на javascript

```
var i = 0;

function p() {
  i = i + 1;
}

console.log(i); // 0
p();
p();
console.log(i); // 2
```

делаем подобное на python

```
global i
i = 1

def p():
    i = i + 1 # UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment

print(i)
p()
p()
print(i)
```

Как сделать подобную функцию?

Comment: В питон не рекомендуется делать такого. Всюду, где можно отказаться от глобальных переменных, лучше от них отказаться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот аналог вашего js кода:

```
i = 0


def p():
    global i
    i += 1


print(i)  # 0
p()
p()
print(i)  # 2
```

Comment: Даже без глобал должно сработать.

Comment: @Эникейщик Поправил текст, теперь надеюсь понятнее :)

Comment: Да, теперь понятнее :)

Answer (score 3):

Перенесите `global` внутрь функции:

```
i = 1
def p():
    global i
    i = i + 1
```

Таким образом Вы сообщаете интерпретатору, что в функции хотите использовать переменную `i` из глобальной области видимости.

Вообще использование `global` не всегда является хорошей практикой. Можно реализовать подобную функцию с возвращаемым значением. Пример

```
def p(i):
    return i+1

i = 1
print(i) # 1
i = p(i)
print(i) # 2
```

Comment: Лучше nonlocal использовать

Answer (score 2):

Кст, `global` нужен только для того, чтобы при присваивании переменной у глобальной было изменено значение, вместо того, чтобы была создана локальная переменная с таким же названием.

Поэтому, можно обойтись без `global` если не будет присваивания конкретной переменной, например:

```
my_global = {
    'i': 1
}

def p():
    my_global['i'] += 1

print(my_global['i'])  # 1
p()
p()
print(my_global['i'])  # 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё вариант

```
i = 1 
def p(i): 
    return i + 1
print(i)
i=p(i)
i=p(i) 
print(i)
```

Comment: Не, это сработает :) выведит `1` и `1`

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь. Ваш вариант выводит 1 1

Comment: @gil9red а, мутабельность же))

Comment: Исправил, теперь сработает

Comment: @eri И опять неправильно :) Теперь ваш вариант не работает вообще. А если добавить return i, тогда будет результат 1 3